# How to generate JPA Static-Metamodel without annotations?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I would like to apply the JPA 2.0 Criteria API to a Hibernate legacy application in order to get type-safe queries. Manual model creation is not an option; neither is the introduction of annotations (i.e. converting *.hbm.xml mappings into JPA annotations).

I tried to use Hibernate's ***"hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.6.Final.jar***" generator without luck so far. The idea was to have a "dummy" entity to kick in Hibernate's annotation processor (`JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`). Then, so my hopes, `JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor` would detect persistence.xml and would eventually be *smart* enough to also detect XML configured entities.

Comment: What does "without luck" mean? Do you get errors? Errors, warnings? I haven't tried, but the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) states the generator will pick up `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` by default *if they are on the classpath*. Note the "tip": you need to add `<persistence-unit-metadata><xml-mapping-metadata-complete/></persistence-unit-metadata>` to your configuration.

Comment: No luck means here: just no doing as expected, i.e. nothing gets generated. Actually, without annotated entities in my classpath, the processor does not kick in, i.e. I'm not even able to pass a processor option like "-Adebug=true" or specify a different configuration resource with "-ApersistenceXml=...".

Comment: I know, this thread is very old. But maybe now you know how to fix this problem, i have the same problem with hbm.xml files nothing is generated.

Comment: @Bagat - eventually I had to bite the bullet and accepted to live without type-safe queries. Sorry.

Comment: I had the same need, typesafe queries without using hibernate metamodel generator. I have created a small open source project exactly for this purpose, please check: https://github.com/grozandrei/exposable

Answer (score 0):

That's a real pity that three years after this question was asked, with Hibernate v. 5.2.12, it's still not easy to find how to generate metamodel without use of annotations. Anyway I am going to describe my solution here as this question (without any answer) pops up as the search result for the query **"Generate metamodel without annotations"**. I struggled a bit with this task, but after all I got there with this ANT task:

```
<target name="jpa_metamodel">
    <delete dir="..\\src_tmp"/>
    <copy todir="..\\src_tmp">
        <fileset dir="..\\src">
            <include name="my/model/package/*.java"/>
            <include name="META-INF/**/*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <replace file="../src_tmp/my/model/package/AbstractEntity.java" token="class" value="@javax.persistence.Entity class"/>
    <javac srcdir="..\\src_tmp"
        destdir="..\\src_jpa_generated"
        failonerror="true"
        fork="false">
        <compilerarg value="-proc:only"/>
        <compilerarg line="-s ..\\src_jpa_generated"/>
        <compilerarg line="-Adebug=true"/>
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="..\\dependencies\\hibernate">
                <include name="**\\*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="../src_tmp"/> <!-- to put META-INF in classpath -->
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Problems with Hibernate medamodel generator are:

- `/META-INF/persistence.xml` and `/META-INF/orm.xml` are searched *in classpath*, and not in source folder. However it seems to be not enough, because after mapping XMLs are added to classpath they are correctly discovered  and generator processes mentioned classes (log entries for every class are emitted), but still, for some reason, no output is produced. So to the next step...
- It seems that it's not really possible to go further without actual annotation. Or maybe it is, but I still don't know how, but I can live with simple workaround. I simply automatically add `@Entity` annotation to temporarily copied sources. Actually I add the annotation in only one file, but in my case it happens to be a root of my entity hierarchy. This might have a meaning, and might not - I did not bother checking. However the need for this step indicates it might be difficult (impossible?) to generate metamodel for entity classes compiled without annotations.
- You need to remember about **-s** compiler arg to store generated *.java files somewhere.

Hope this might be helpful for someone in the future.